# Brew from an out of date kit - not fermented

Tags: beer, stuck-fermentation

I kicked off a wildly out of date (2008) brew from a kit a few weeks ago. ( One of those kits with a packet of yeast and 2 large tins of goop.)

The brewing didnt go as well as I've had them go previously, but there was some pressure under the brew bucket lid.

Anyway I checked the hydrometer and it seemed ok.  So I barrelled it with the extra bit of sugar too.

However a week or so later there's no pressure at all in the barrel.

So, I guess should I:

a) Decant back to the bucket and try again with another packet of yeast?
b) give up and get a kit that is in date? :)

Comment: Did you see a krausen in the brew bucket? A thick off white foam on top of the beer? If not, the yeast were dead and the beer has been feremneted by wild yeast and bacteria. Did you taste the gravity sample? That will give you an indication about whether it's worth continuing with this brew or not.

Comment: Not much no. I tasted some from the barrel and it was pretty horrible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't waste time on such an out of date kit. Even if you get a new sachet of yeast (the supplied yeast is almost certainly not viable) the extract 'goop" will probably have staled, tasting soapy and bitter.

You're better off getting a fresh kit. My very first brew was also a 5 year old kit, and all I produced was 20 liters of vinegar.

Comment: Thanks, I've started another kit!  If this works fine I'll know there was nothing I did wrong other than it being out of date! no harm in trying tho!